# SKPhysicsJointSpring frequency & damping in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

What is the difference between `damping` and `frequency` properties of a `SKPhysicsJointSpring` ?

the code I have is

```
var spring = SKPhysicsJointSpring.jointWithBodyA(
            body1.physicsBody,
            bodyB: body2.physicsBody,
            anchorA: body1.position,
            anchorB: body2.position)
spring.frequency = 1.8
spring.damping = 0.5
self.physicsWorld.addJoint(spring1)

body1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
body2.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
```

In what range of values should `frequency` and `damping` fall so that the `spring` acts *naturally*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer depends on what you consider "natural".

Damping means that the spring will dissipate energy with each oscillation and eventually come to rest.

Zero damping means that the mass attached to the spring will oscillate forever.

Such a system usually has three constants associated with it:

1. mass m (lbm)
2. spring stiffness k (lbf/in)
3. damping coefficient c

It's well known that frequency f^2 = k/m.

When that system talks about spring "frequency" it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, so what sample values could I use for `mass`, `frequency` and `damping`? and How would the bounciness be affected if one of those changes?

Comment: "Bounciness" is controlled by the mass m and spring stiffness k.  Make damping coefficiet c = 0 for now.  Higher stiffness, lower mass mean higher frequency; lower stiffness, higher mass means lower frequency.

Comment: lbm, lbf, in? What about kg, N or m? (Just kidding :)

Comment: You mean the rational units that the rest of the world uses?  You got me, @MartinR.

Comment: @Carpsen90: I've given you something more valuable than code.  You have to actually learn a little about physics to do this problem properly.

Comment: Thank you for everything

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to think of frequency as a measure of the spring's "stiffness", how it responds to compressive or lateral forces. Higher frequency means a stiffer spring. You'll often see values like `4.0` or `9.0`. A frequency of `0.0001` is very, very loose!

However, a word of caution: this logic breaks down at the default frequency of `0.0`. At `frequency == 0.0`, the spring is entirely rigid and non-compressive.